# Will Custom intents declared in the app using Android capability elements available for users to access from Google devices using google assistant?

Tags: google-smart-home, google-assistant, app-actions, customintents

Since the conversational actions are going to be deprecated, need to find an alternative.

When checked in the google documents it was found that app actions and smart home actions would be better alternatives. But it is unclear if the Custom intents will be available for the Google home devices.

I am expecting the App actions with custom intents to work from Google home devices.

Answer (score 0):

Custom intents were supported previously as part of Conversational Actions. They are currently not supported within Smart Home actions. Custom intents are still supported as part of Android app actions.